# Disable hostname verifier in servlet with CAS

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, cas

I have CAS deployed on a virtual machine (in jboss) and I'm trying to use cas login in a servlet, but using SAML protocol in filters for Authentication and Validation, I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present`
In the future I'll receive a proper certificate, but until then I want to disable this hostname verifier, for testing. I know I should @Override some code, but I don't know how and where to do this in my servlet which connects to CAS through filters that are in web.xml. Currently my servlet just Overrides doGET method to print something that I should receive from CAS. Can someone help me, please?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** This is the exact error that I see in logs

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/casuser].[cas]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet cas threw exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(Saml11TicketValidator.java:275) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:200) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:206) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:100) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Saml11TicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(Saml11TicketValidator.java:259) [cas-client-core-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428) [jsse.jar:1.7.0_79]
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set p:cookieSecure="false" for the ticketGrantingTicketCookieGenerator.

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Securing+Your+New+CAS+Server

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It seems my default CAS already has set to false, that cookieSecure.